# What is the state of ASP.NET MVC Contrib UI Testing Helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, web-testing, gui-testing

Back in April I was listening to Herding Code episode 77 about MvcContrib.

There Eric Hexter announced UI Testing Helpers as a big upcoming feature.

Now several months later I was searching the web for any information about UI testing with MvcContrib.
Unfortunately I found almost nothing:

This sneek peek:
http://codepaste.net/cw8ie4

And this (abandoned?) code on github:
http://github.com/mvccontrib/MvcContrib/tree/master/src/MvcContrib.TestHelper/MvcContrib.TestHelper/Ui/

So I was wondering what is the current state of UI testing support in MvcContrib?
Is there any active development? Is anybody using them? Have they be abandoned? Why?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MvcContrib.TestHelpers.dll (and a WatiN driver) is included in the latest release of MvcContrib (in the MVCContrib.Extras.release.zip)

[MvcContrib is currently being developed on Codeplex](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/). The github repository is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks!
Judging from searching the web it seems that those helpers did not gain much attraction... is this impression correct?

What would be the main benefit over using WatiN directly?